# MapView not loading in google places android project

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on a tutorial i found on android hive for google places.There is a button which shows the places as markers on the next acitivity.The problem is the markers are shown but the background is gray , i.e the map is not shown

The java code for that class is:

```
package com.androidhive.googleplacesandmaps;

import java.util.List;



import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class PlacesMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    // Nearest places
    PlacesList nearPlaces;

    // Map view
    MapView mapView;

    // Map overlay items
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    // Map controllers
    MapController mc;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    OverlayItem overlayitem;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

        // Getting intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Users current geo location
        String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
        String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

        // Nearplaces list
        nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Geopoint to place on map
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

        // Map overlay item
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
                "That is you!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        // These values are used to get map boundary area
        // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // check for null in case it is null
        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
            // loop through all the places
            for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
                latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
                longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

                // Geopoint to place on map
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));

                // Map overlay item
                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                        place.vicinity);

                itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


                // calculating map boundary area
                minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
                minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
                maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
                maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            // showing all overlay items
            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
        }

        // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

        // Showing the center of the map
        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
        mapView.postInvalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyA-TRW4lRKMdeg5GdwWHjTOJnscCLFm-eA"
/>
```

I have used the api key i generated for the project .Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Dude first read the documentation.
The version you are using is currently not Active.
**You need to use Google Map API V2.**
Follow the Below link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/